# Add CDN CSS before style.css in genesis

Tags: css, wordpress, genesis

I'm not new to WordPress and using WordPress over 4 years. I want add extra external CSS from specific URL.

I know how to add CSS from my theme.

But I want add extra external CSS before style.css  How to do this in genesis framework.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problems is single quotes

```
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_stylesheet' );
    function my_stylesheet() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.css' );
    }
```

Comment: It works only when I hosted that custom CSS on my theme. But I have no idea about how to extra external CSS from CDN.

Comment: get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.css' replace by online url

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of including fontsawesome stylesheet using external url from their CDN.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_stylesheet' );
function my_stylesheet() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
}
```

Comment: How to add this cdn css before style.css